# Object lifecycle seems to stop working on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've set 3 day TTL on a bucket and it has been working for about a month.
but in last 10 days nothing has been removed from the bucket. I've checked if the lifecycle rule still exists on the bucket using `gsutil lifecycle get bucket` and it is still there:

```
{"rule": [{"action": {"type": "Delete"}, "condition": {"age": 3}}]}
```

Is the rule correct? if yes what could be the problem?